# Apache Tiles and Spring Model Objects

Tags: forms, spring, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

The Header section (Apache Tiles Attribute) is shared by several views. It has a form that expects an Object when the page is loaded and complains if the Object is missing.  At the moment I am placing the Object in a Model and passing it to the View using the Controller every time I create a view that inherits this layout.

This approach seems rather tedious as i have repeated lines all over the Controller.  I'd like to be able to add it once and be done with.

I am not too familiar with Apache Tiles there maybe a simple solution that I am not aware of.

Looking for some helpful tips.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` class and the `postHandle` method to achieve something like that. By cons, you will need to define a rule that will help you to know when the object need to be add to the model, it can be the path or something in the url, it depends on how your template is organized. Here an example of an interceptor that is doing something like that.

The interceptor defenition :

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="your.package.HeaderModelInterceptor"/>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

The interceptor class :

```
public class HeaderModelInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
        ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {

        // Check if you need to add the object
        if (Your rule) {
            modelAndView.addObject("headerObject", headerObject);
        }

        super.postHandle(request, response, handler, modelAndView);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options to do this. Off the top of my head you could.

1. Use Tiles view preparers, [simple example here](http://richardbarabe.wordpress.com/2009/02/19/apache-tiles-2-viewpreparer-example/)
2. Use a mechanism like Spring interceptors or AOP to automatically add your object to the Model instead of repeating the code everywhere

It really depends on the nature of the object you're adding and how much context it needs.

Comment: I solved this once using a Servlet Filter.  In my case, I was pre-loading menus from a DB and simply shoving them into the session.